# i have error to recognize folder in node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

This is my html code

```
<div id="done_work_1" class="logo-slide-track">
</div>
<script>$.ajax({
    url: "/static/home/done/",
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if (val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif|JPG)$/)) {
                $("#done_work_1").append("<div class='slide'><img src='" + val + "'></div>");
                $("#done_work_2").append("<div class='slide'><img src='" + val + "'></div>");
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

And this is my server.js file in node.js

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/template/home.html');
});

app.use('/static/home', express.static('static/home'));
app.use(express.static('static/home'));
app.use('/static/home/done', express.static('static/home/done'));
app.use(express.static('static/home/done'));
```

My image is in this location `static/home/done`

But when I run the node server.js on localhost, I get this error in the console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) ----http://127.0.0.1:4400/static/home/done/

I want use jQuery code say in up to load image inside (static/home/done) file but I get this error - how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should first tell the express that here are my static files then you can work with your routes.

```
app.use('/static/home', express.static('static/home'));
app.use(express.static('static/home'));
app.use('/static/home/done', express.static('static/home/done'));
app.use(express.static('static/home/done'));
app.post("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/template/home.html');
});
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with this case and it does not work